# Passing array from Javascript to Actionscript 2

Tags: javascript, actionscript-2

I need to import from inside flash an Array from a JS function, and display it in Dynamic Text in Flash, my code is :

AS2:

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

js_btn.onRelease = function() {
    _root.infoBox.text = ExternalInterface.call("getUserInfo()");
}
```

JS:

```
function getUserInfo() {
    var userinfo = {fullname: 'George One', username: 'goergeo', picturelink: 'http://link.com'};
    return userinfo;
}
```

Once I press the button, I get "undefined" in the text box!
Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct AS2 code is as below:

```
import flash.external.*;

js_btn.onPress = function() {
    allUserInfo = Object(ExternalInterface.call("getUserInfo"));
    _root.infoBox.text = allUserInfo["fullname"];
}
```